# Can't install Windows 7, software center crashing

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

This computer came with Ubuntu installed and I want to install Windows 7 from a USB. For some reason it won't let me. I've mounted the ISO onto the USB and tried to boot from it (with safe boot disabled) but it just goes straight back into Ubuntu. I thought maybe I needed an NTFS partition in order for it to work so I tried downloading GParted and the software center crashed. Now it won't let me install it or cancel my current installation that isn't working.

I've tried to look up other ways of making partitons but I only have the 1 USB and no way to make a live CD without wiping the one with Windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy iso file to usb, you need to [create bootable flash drive](http://lifehacker.com/5423747/windows-7-usb-download-tool-lets-you-install-windows-from-a-thumb-drive). Also, you can create live DVD of your Ubuntu and partition the drive or download one from [Ubuntu home page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

Comment: How do I partition my drive without GPart? I can't get it to install because a former installation is being canceled and it never finishes, so everything I'm trying to install is just waiting on it.

Comment: You can run GPart from live DVD.

Comment: I don't have any spare DVDs or USBs I can use at the moment, I've just been trying to install it from the software center.

Comment: You can't run windows applications from Ubuntu software centar except with Wine. If GParted doesn't work, you can try similar apps http://alternativeto.net/software/gparted/